# How can i get hyperlinks text from textview android?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I am working on text-view.in that text-view display html hyperlink.
when i click on hyper-linked text then i want to get that text.

[image]

as per above image if i click on hyperlink, then i want to display text.

***Your answer would be appreciated***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The LinkEnableTextView class is like this:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class LinkEnabledTextView  extends TextView
{
// The String Containing the Text that we have to gather links from private SpannableString linkableText;
// Populating and gathering all the links that are present in the Text
private ArrayList<Hyperlink> listOfLinks; 

// A Listener Class for generally sending the Clicks to the one which requires it
TextLinkClickListener mListener;

// Pattern for gathering @usernames from the Text
Pattern screenNamePattern = Pattern.compile('(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)');

// Pattern for gathering #hasttags from the Text
Pattern hashTagsPattern = Pattern.compile('(#[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)');

// Pattern for gathering http:// links from the Text
Pattern hyperLinksPattern = Pattern.compile('([Hh][tT][tT][pP][sS]?:\\/\\/[^ ,'\'>\\]\\)]*[^\\. ,'\'>\\]\\)])');

public LinkEnabledTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    listOfLinks = new ArrayList<Hyperlink>();

}

public void gatherLinksForText(String text)
{
    linkableText = new SpannableString(text);
 //gatherLinks basically collects the Links depending upon the Pattern that we supply
 //and add the links to the ArrayList of the links

    gatherLinks(listOfLinks, linkableText, screenNamePattern);
    gatherLinks(listOfLinks, linkableText, hashTagsPattern);
    gatherLinks(listOfLinks, linkableText, hyperLinksPattern);

    for(int i = 0; i< listOfLinks.size(); i++)
    {
        Hyperlink linkSpec = listOfLinks.get(i);
        android.util.Log.v('listOfLinks :: ' + linkSpec.textSpan, 'listOfLinks :: ' + linkSpec.textSpan);

        // this process here makes the Clickable Links from the text

        linkableText.setSpan(linkSpec.span, linkSpec.start, linkSpec.end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }


     // sets the text for the TextView with enabled links

    setText(linkableText);
}


 // sets the Listener for later click propagation purpose

public void setOnTextLinkClickListener(TextLinkClickListener newListener)
{
    mListener = newListener;
}

  //The Method mainly performs the Regex Comparison for the Pattern and adds them to
  //listOfLinks array list


private final void gatherLinks(ArrayList<Hyperlink> links,
                               Spannable s, Pattern pattern)
{
    // Matcher matching the pattern
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (m.find())
    {
        int start = m.start();
        int end = m.end();


    // Hyperlink is basically used like a structure for storing the information about
    // where the link was found.

        Hyperlink spec = new Hyperlink();

        spec.textSpan = s.subSequence(start, end);
        spec.span = new InternalURLSpan(spec.textSpan.toString());
        spec.start = start;
        spec.end = end;

        links.add(spec);
    }
}


// This is class which gives us the clicks on the links which we then can use.


public class InternalURLSpan extends ClickableSpan
{
    private String clickedSpan;

    public InternalURLSpan (String clickedString)
    {
        clickedSpan = clickedString;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView)
    {
        mListener.onTextLinkClick(textView, clickedSpan);
    }
}


// Class for storing the information about the Link Location


class Hyperlink
{
    CharSequence textSpan;
    InternalURLSpan span;
    int start;
    int end;
}
```

Now, having this you require just another interface for propagating the clicks to the place you require to handle them in my case I implemented the interface in my Activity and simple wrote a Log Command there.
The TextLinkClickListener interface is like this:

```
import android.view.View;

public interface TextLinkClickListener
{


  //  This method is called when the TextLink is clicked from LinkEnabledTextView

public void onTextLinkClick(View textView, String clickedString)
}
```

After doing all this you just require to create an Activity using the Custom LinkEnabledTextView and check the things out yourself. There are a few things that you must do while creating a object of the Custom LinkEnabledTextView those are mentioned and described in the Code of the Activity below:

```
import android.text.method.MovementMethod;
import com.umundoinc.Tvider.Component.LinkEnabledTextView.LinkEnabledTextView;
import com.umundoinc.Tvider.Component.LinkEnabledTextView.TextLinkClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;

//Here the Activity is implementing the TextLinkClickListener the one we have created
//the Clicks over the Links are forwarded over here from the LinkEnabledTextView

public class TextViewActivity  extends Activity  implements TextLinkClickListener 
{
private LinkEnabledTextView check;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    String text  =  "This is a #test of regular expressions with http://example.com/ links as used in @twitter for performing various operations based on the links this handles multiple links like http://this_is_fun.com/ and #Awesomess and @Cool";

    check = new LinkEnabledTextView(this, null);
    check.setOnTextLinkClickListener(this);
    check.gatherLinksForText(text);
    check.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    check.setLinkTextColor(Color.GREEN);

    MovementMethod m = check.getMovementMethod();
    if ((m == null) || !(m instanceof LinkMovementMethod)) {
        if (check.getLinksClickable()) {
            check.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }

    setContentView(check);
}

public void onTextLinkClick(View textView, String clickedString)
{
    android.util.Log.v('Hyperlink clicked is :: ' + clickedString, 'Hyperlink clicked is :: ' + clickedString);
}
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: can you put full code? when i integrating this code ,i stuck with errors.

Comment: Here is reference link for the same code. Please follow all the things and you'll get your things done. http://www.orangeapple.org/post/14809024490/android-custom-hyperlinked-textview#.Vrsqp_l96Uk. And please upvote if it helped you my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Please try my Implementation:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ........

     textView mTvTxt = findViewById(R.id.tv_txt_view);

    final String hyperlink =  "Vasant jetava";  

    SpannableString spannableString = makeLinkSpan(hyperlink , new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               showDialog(hyperlink)
        }
    });

    mTvTxt.setText(getString("hello whats up man....");
    mTvTxt.append(spannableString);
    makeLinksFocusable(mTvTxt);
}       
 private SpannableString makeLinkSpan(CharSequence text, View.OnClickListener listener) {

    SpannableString link = new SpannableString(text);
    link.setSpan(new ClickableString(listener), 0, text.length(),
            SpannableString.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return link;


private void makeLinksFocusable(TextView tv) {
    MovementMethod m = tv.getMovementMethod();
    if ((m == null) || !(m instanceof LinkMovementMethod)) {
        if (tv.getLinksClickable()) {
            tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }
}



private static class ClickableString extends ClickableSpan {
        private View.OnClickListener mListener;

        public ClickableString(View.OnClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onClick(v);
        }
    }
private void showDialog(String message){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(<YourActivityName>this).create(); //Read Update
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        alertDialog.setButton("Continue..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // here you can add functions
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: i implemented your code but when i click on link.it gives me error.

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=$ (has extras) }

Comment: @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               // Do your action - Previously added my implementation. It's a copy paste issue.
        }

Comment: i just wann open simple dialog with hyperlink clicked text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103081/discussion-between-nithinjith-and-vasant).